# How to use dropbox API from chrome extension content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

If I write a chrome extension, it normally consist of multiple parts:

1. One is the **devtools page** which is a normal HTML page with origin set to
   "chrome-extension://<guid>/filename". On that page I can use
   the Dropbox API to get user confirmation via HTML popup and then use
   the saved auth info and do all work via the Dropbox javascript library.
2. Another part of extension is the **content script** which is executed
   in the context of specified third-party web pages ("injected") and have
   origin cookies and web storage shared with them.

Is it possible to also use the Dropbox JavaScript library in that content script?

I can't call `authenticate` in interactive mode since it will re-ask for confirmation for each different webpage I'm injected into. And calling `authenticate` without interactive will fail since the content script doesn't share the origin, cookies and web storage with the devtools extension page :(. Maybe there's some way to "pass" the Dropbox auth info from the part of the extension that offers GUI and where user successfully confirms dropbox usage to the parts of the extension that are GUI-less, like content script or background page?

Comment: You should maybe make your question easier to read

Comment: @kzahel Thanks! any specific recommendations?

Comment: Why not have the content-script make requests to background page, and have the background page make the actual dropbox requests, and return the results to content-script?

Comment: @levi It's one of possible solution. But if it's possible to just use dropbox api in content script - why write more code to do exactly same task? :)

Comment: @EyeofHell Look at the dropbox HTTP API. It should be possible to make the underlying requests which power the js library. This way you can pass it exactly what it needs to authenticate.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

Comment: @EyeofHell Did you figure something out for this yet? Note that you can initialize a `Dropbox.Client` with a token instead of an app key, so once you've done the auth, there should presumably be a way to get that token over to the content script and just do `new Dropbox.Client({token: <token>});`

Comment: @smarx Not yet. Will try to communicate with dropbox devs.

Comment: I'm a dev advocate at Dropbox. :-)

Comment: @smarx That's very good! What do you mean by "there should presumably be a way to get that token over to the content scrip". Is it any API of Client or AuthDriver objects i can use to get this token or i need to hack into RAW javascript objects?

Comment: I mean I don't know exactly where it's stored in the Chrome extension AuthDriver, and I don't know how you communicate data between two parts of your app. But I imagine it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to get Facebook working from code injected into a web app via a content script. I suspect there are multiple ways, but what I did was take advantage of the [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) API to do the OAuth work for me, specifically the [`launchWebAuthFlow()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).

This can only be done in the background page (in my case an event page), but I send messages to the event page which replies with the `access_token`, which can then be used in URLs in the same was as the 'web' technique - i.e. in HTTP requests with XHR.

You can send/receive messages via the content script (using events on `document`), but I decided to do it [directly using "external" messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) with the [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) API in the web app context, and [`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) in the background script. This requires adding "matches" for the URLs you're injecting code into in an [`"externally_connectable"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) section of the manifest.json.

I believe this can be adapted to make it work with Dropbox.

Comment: While this does not _directly_ answer the question, I personally defend this answer as demonstrating the proper technique - it just needs to be adapted. Poor choice of words by the author at the end, which I now edited. Please do not delete-vote.